# How to make a given matrix symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given the real square block matrix 
$
M = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
A & D^t & 0\\ D & c E & c F\\ 0 & H & J
\end{pmatrix}
$
how can I make it symmetric?
Note that the dimension of $F$ is $n \times m$ and the dimension of $H$ is $m \times n$ so that I think I require $H = F^t$ to make it symmetric.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix) states that I can compute matrices $D$ and $S$ such that $M = DS$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $S$ is a symmetric matrix, the question is how do I get those matrices.
I think that the matrices would look like
$
D = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 I & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & ? & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & ?
\end{pmatrix}
$
and
$
S = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 A & D^t & 0 \\ D & ? & ? \\ 0 & ? & ?
\end{pmatrix}
$
but again I am not sure how to compute them.
Any help is really appreciated since I am completely lost, a reference link with an example would be of great help.

Comment: Given a square matrix $N$ the matrix $N+N^T$ is symmetric.

Comment: Not all nonsymmetric matrices can be made symmetric just by a diagonal scaling.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel, what do you mean by diagonal scaling? How would scaling the diagonal make a non-symmetric matrix symmetric?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye What do I mean? Probably it is somehow related to the contents of the question?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel, I understood it was related to the question, but I still don't know what diagonal scaling is. Why do you answer me like that, do you think it is a very helpful answer?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye I do not think my "answer" is helpful since I did not understand what you ask for. The question is whether for the given matrix $M$ there is a diagonal (and nonsingular) matrix $D$ such that $M=DS$, where $S$ is symmetric. $D$ is diagonal and multiplication by a diagonal matrix may be referred to as *diagonal scaling* (not scaling *of* the diagonal).